# Calling enum methods from outside

Tags: java, interface, enums, abstraction

the code is

```
public interface Command {
     public Command[] parseCommand(String command);
}

public enum CameraCommand implements Command {
    CLICK;  
    public Command[] parseCommand(String commands) {
    if ("CLICK".equals(commands))
        return new Command[] { CameraCommand.CLICK };
        return null;
    }
}

public enum RoverCommand implements Command {

    L,
    R,
    M;

public Command[] parseCommand(String commandString) {
    RoverCommand[] commands = new RoverCommand[commandString.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < commandString.length(); i++) {
        switch (commandString.charAt(i)) {
        case 'L':
            commands[i] = RoverCommand.L;
            break;
        case 'R':
            commands[i] = RoverCommand.R;
            break;
        case 'M':
            commands[i] = RoverCommand.M;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return commands;
}
}
```

I did this to group the commands type.
now the problem is, I get a command of particular type in string, ex "CLICK". I do not know the type, but I wish to do like this

```
Machine machine = getMachine(type); //machine is an interface, i pass type and get a typeof machine
//machine.parseCommand(commandString); //i don wish to have this logic inside the machine
Command[] command = Command.parseCommand(commandString); // this didnt work, how to solve this, work around?
machine.execute(command); ///finally pass the command and execute the action
```

any help would be appreciated

thanks
V

Comment: There is no question here. Please make sure that when you ask a question on Stackoverflow, *you actually include a question mark somewhere*

Answer (score 3):

You can do like `RoverCommand.L.parseCommand`, because you need an instance of Command interfrace to call method.
But you should consider making `parseCommand` static method. For example in RoverCommand make it static and call RoverCommand.parseCommand.

I think you should spearate all commands in `commandString` by for example spaces. And then parse every single command, delimited by spaces, using one static method, which decides if it is "CLICK" or "L" or "R" or "M".
E.g.

```
String commandsString = "L CLICK R L CLICK";
List<Command> commands = CommandParser.parseCommands(commandsString);

public class CommandParser {
    public static Command parseSingleCommand(String command) {
        if ("CLICK".equals(command)) { return CameraCommand.CLICK; }
        else if ("R".equals(command)) { return RoverCommand.R; }
        else if ("L".equals(command)) { return RoverCommand.L; }
        else if ("M".equals(command)) { return RoverCommand.M; }
        else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown command: " + command); }
    }

    public static List<Command> parseCommands(String commandsString) {
       String[] commands = commandsString.split(" ");
       List<Command> result = new ArrayList<Command>();
       for (String command : commands) {
          result.add(CommandParser.parseSingleCommand(command));
       }
       return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are acting on class level not instace level. TO solve this you should declare your method parseCommand as static.

```
public static Command[] parseCommand(String commandString) {
    RoverCommand[] commands = new RoverCommand[commandString.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < commandString.length(); i++) {
        switch (commandString.charAt(i)) {
        case 'L':
            commands[i] = RoverCommand.L;
            break;
        case 'R':
            commands[i] = RoverCommand.R;
            break;
        case 'M':
            commands[i] = RoverCommand.M;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return commands;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have alot of boiler plate code you don't need.  If you do it this way you can add Commands without having to add code as well.

```
public interface Command {
}

public enum Commands {
    ;

    public static Command[] parseCommand(String command) {
        for (Class type : new Class[]{CameraCommand.class, RoverCommand.class})
            try {
                return new Command[]{(Command) Enum.valueOf(type, command)};
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
            }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Command " + command);
    }
}

public enum CameraCommand implements Command {
    CLICK
}

public enum RoverCommand implements Command {
    L, R, M;
}
```